# How to dynamically generate javascript objects within other objects. Can you use a for loop inside an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I hope to achieve a set of javascript objects something like this:

```
tabs[0]={
 sections[0]={
      title:"section0",
      children[0]={
           title:"Child0"
      },
      children[1]={
           title:"Child1"
      },
      children[2]={
           title:"Child2"
      }
 },
 sections[1]={
      title:"section1",
      children[0]={
           title:"Child0"
      },
      children[1]={
           title:"Child1"
      }
 }
 };
tabs[1]={
 sections[0]={
      title:"section0",
      children[0]={
           title:"Child0"
      },
      children[1]={
           title:"Child1"
      }
 },
 sections[1]={
      title:"section1",
      children[0]={
           title:"Child0"
      },
      children[1]={
           title:"Child1"
      }
 },
 sections[2]={
      title:"section2",
      children[0]={
           title:"Child0"
      },
      children[1]={
           title:"Child1"
      }
 }
```

};

Here is my code but I'm getting an "Unexpected Token" error at the first for loop within the tab object. Is this not allowed? How could I read these arrays and create objects like those above dynamically? The arrays (and subsequently the objects) can and will change as the .csv files change, which is why I need to dynamically create these objects. These objects will be used in with AngularJS's ng-repeat to create the tabbed and side navigation for an app.

```
 this.tabData = tabsService.tabData;
    var tabCount = tabsService.tabData.length;
    var tabs={};
    var tCounter = 0;
    for (tCounter; tCounter<tabCount; tCounter++){
    var tabURL = "Contents/Product Groups/"+this.tabData[tCounter]+"/sectionOrder.csv";

    tabs[tCounter] ={
        "TabSectionData" : $.getCsvArray(tabs[tCounter].tabURL), //gets array from csv file
        "sectionCount" : TabSectionData.length

            for (sCounter = 0; sCounter<tabs[tCounter].sectionCount; sCounter++){
            "tabChildURL" : "Contents/Product Groups/"+this.tabData[tCounter]+"/"+tabs[tCounter].TabSectionData[sCounter]+"/order.csv", 
            "TabChildData" : $.getCsvArray(tabChildURL) //gets array from csv file

            sections[sCounter] ={
                "title" = tabs[tCounter].TabSectionData.[sCounter];
                cCounter = 0;
                for (cCounter = 0; cCounter<TabChildData.length; cCounter++){
                        children[cCounter]={
                        "title": tabs[tCounter].TabSectionData[sCounter].TabChildData.[cCounter]

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't have a `for` loop inside an object literal. But there's no reason you can't use one to add properties to the object after creating it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a loop inside a function and instantly execute the function.
I created a Snippet to exemplify.

```js
var obj = {
    name: 'My Object',
    sections: (function () {
        var result = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var it = {};
            result[i] = it;
            
            it.title = 'Hello';

            it.children = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                it.children[j] = 'children' + j;
            }
        }

        return result;
    })()
};

var json = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
jQuery('pre').append(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, 'Can you use for loop inside an object [literal] ', perhaps to create a list of properties, you may do something like this:

Enclose your `for` loop inside an immediately invoked function. From that function `return` the result of the loop.

For example:

I want to dynamically add an array of properties using for loop.

```
var items = {

    list : (function(){    // immediately invoked function

            var arr = []; // array

            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                arr.push('item no. '+i); // add each item to array
            }

            return arr;   // return the array as value of the list property          

        })()
}
```

RESULT:
 items = {
   list : [
    "item no. 0",
    "item no. 1",
    "item no. 2",
    "item no. 3"
]
}